# Routing to a different gateway depending on destination for Windows Network

Tags: routing, active-directory, tcpip, ip-routing

I have a small network on a single VLAN 10.  It's a 192.168.100.x network with a firewall/NAT sitting at .254.  Our company relies on some data feeds that are brought into the network via dedicated circuits (T1's).  The routers for those dedicated circuits have a static address in the 192.168.100.x network (for example: 192.168.100.15).  We need to connect to servers on the other side of those dedicated circuits, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

I'm looking to add a static route that says if one of the clients in my 192.168.100.x network attempts to access a computer that exists on a AAA.BBB.CCC.X Class C network, that it always uses the dedicated router at 192.168.100.15 as its gateway.

Can anyone provide some help for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to do this either on the clients or on the 254 gateway:

```
route add AAA.BBB.CCC.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.100.15
```

But it's not clear from your question whether it will just work. The dedicated router may need to provide NAT too.

Comment: I'm struggling with this answer because it seems like I may be forced into creating VLANs where the managed switch can route it to the appropriate VLAN depending on the destination.  The alternative would be creating static routes on each client?

Comment: The best place to do this is usually on your default gateway, because then you only have to do it once. If your firewall/NAT device can accept static routes, you may be able to add it there. For example, the other hosts on your network will try to get to AAA.BBB.CCC.X via 192.168.100.254 (their default gateway), which will issue an ICMP redirect to 192.168.100.15 (the dedicated router). Gleb is correct that the router at 15 may still need to provide NAT in order for you to communicate with hosts in AAA.BBB.CCC.0/24.

Comment: I suspect most kinds of hosts will ignore ICMP redirects so traffic will always bounce off the 254 gateway which would make me uncomfortable. :) But if configuring clients with static route needs to be avoided -- OK then.

Comment: It sounds like the approach we're going to take is a dedicated router that will decide based on the destination network where to send the traffic.  I really appreciate the information Gleb.